# MPMoviePlayerController Background playing

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

Okay guys i have a problem. I'm stream MPMoviePlayerController and i want it to play audio in background and i've somewhat achieved this.

This is what i do in my `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Now whenever the application calls `-applicationWillResignActive:`
i do a post notification to continue the playback. And this works but it's an ugly fix. As there is a second delay between the sound stopping and the notification being called. So the playback stops for a second and then continues again by calling the notification which just says `[viewPlayer play];`

And many other have achieved smooth background playback. Like spotify or other apps whenever you enter background mode there is no sound lag/clipping in sound. This is really annoying to listen to whenever i press the home button or lock the phone.

Yes i did set the background mode for playback.

I have also tried `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` but this notification is even slower. It comes after `-applicationWillResignActive:`

I have no idea how to fix this, and or how others achieved it. I have looked through almost all other similar questions. None have my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently used a [framework](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) to stream YouTube video inline in a `UIView`. This framework has a category on `MPMoviePlayerController` which works pretty well. You notice a change in the music when going to background but it is still acceptable.

The category can be found here:

[MPMoviePlayerController+BackgroundPlayback.h](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/blob/master/XCDYouTubeKit%20Demo/iOS%20Demo/MPMoviePlayerController%2BBackgroundPlayback.h)
[MPMoviePlayerController+BackgroundPlayback.m](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/blob/master/XCDYouTubeKit%20Demo/iOS%20Demo/MPMoviePlayerController%2BBackgroundPlayback.m)

Comment: Thanks dude, but that didn't help. I was trying to get rid of the change in the music when going to background.